# "ResultSet not positioned properly" Called .next() but still doesn't work, please advise?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to pull data about songs out of a database I have created using postgresql. I have been getting this error and I don't know what to do as I have called resultSet.next(). 
Any advice?

```
     String SQL = "SELECT trackName, albumName FROM tracks, artists, 
     albums WHERE 'song' = tracks.trackname AND tracks.mainartist = 
     artists.artistname AND albums.artist = artists.artistname";

    try
    {
        org.postgresql.Driver.isRegistered();
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password); //creates a new connection

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
        resultSet.next();


        String album = resultSet.getString(3);
        String artist = resultSet.getString(4);
        String trackName = resultSet.getString(2);
        String feat = resultSet.getString(5);
        String date = resultSet.getString(6);

        console.println("");
        console.println("");
        console.println("Track Name: "+trackName);
        console.println("");
        console.println("Track Album: "+album);
        console.println("");
        console.println("Track Artist(s): "+artist);
        console.println("");
        console.println("Featuring: "+feat);
        console.println("");
        console.println("Track Release Date: "+date);
        console.println("");
        console.println("\n");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        console.println("SORRY, COULD NOT CONNECT YOU TO THE DATABASE.");
        console.println(e);
        console.println("");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting this printed out in the terminal:

```
    SORRY, COULD NOT CONNECT YOU TO THE DATABASE.
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, 
    perhaps you need to call next.
```

And this is the stackTrace:

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.checkResultSet(PgResultSet.java:2772)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getString(PgResultSet.java:1894)
at Info.songInfo(Info.java:49)
at __SHELL14.run(__SHELL14.java:5)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:752)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should always check the return value from `next` before trying to retrieve information from a row, because you may not be on a row. From [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()):

> Returns: `true` if the new current row is valid; `false` if there are no more rows

I suspect your query isn't matching any rows, so `next` is returning `false`, but then you're trying to read from a non-existant row.

So in your case:

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
    String album = resultSet.getString(3);
    // ...
} else {
    // There were no matching rows
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it is now jumping to the else statement, any clue why this may be?

Comment: Possibly your query does not return anything? Run it manually via psql in terminal, and make sure you actually get some returned rows.

Comment: @GabePitchford - Because your query isn't returning anything.

Comment: Should the query not return trackname and albumname??

Comment: @GabePitchford - Only if there are matching rows. Apparently, there aren't. I suggest following Filip's advice above.

Comment: I tried doing this and it is in fact not returning anything, would anyone be able to help me as to understand why this is or what I could change it to?

Comment: @GabePitchford - That's a completely different question. I'd suggest looking carefully at the query and the data in your database and, if you can't figure it out, post a new question with your structure, your query, an explanation of why you think it matches, and a list of the rows that you think should match from the various source tables. Then people will be able to help you understand why the query doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you think this query should return value? You can get / install PGAdmin tool, connect it to this database and fire the same query, see if you are getting anything back.
Alternately, use following query (without specific predicates in where clause) and see what result you get back
**String SQL = "SELECT trackName, albumName FROM tracks t, artists a join t.mainartist = a.artistname**